# How to force SPECIFIC PAGES to force desktop view in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, viewport

I hope you were fine these days.
  I want to make **ONLY SPECIFIC PAGES** force to get Desktop view on mobile **NOT WHOLE WEBSITE**.
I know about the viewport tag. I want to know how can I do this thing for some pages.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this help? https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by [creating a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and overriding the **header** template of your parent theme. To do that, copy the `header.php` file of your parent theme to your child theme's directory.

Modify `header.php` and remove the viewport meta tag.

For example, in the default WordPress theme (Twenty Twenty) that means this line:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
```

Now, you can hook into [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) and add a different meta tag depending on the page.

To target a specific page, you can use [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/), which accepts a **page ID**, **title**, **slug**, or **array of such** to check against.

For example:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_viewport_meta' );

function add_viewport_meta() {
  // Force desktop view only on the page with a slug of 'about-us'
  if ( is_page( 'about-us' ) ) {
    $viewport_meta = 'width=1024'; // desktop
  } else {
    $viewport_meta = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0';  // responsive
  }
  ?>

    <meta name="viewport" content="<?php echo $viewport_meta; ?>">

  <?php
}
```

---

**Edit:** Since you mentioned that the viewport meta with 'width=1024' as the content didn't work, you could try to omit it entirely on desktop.

This would like this:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_viewport_meta' );

function add_viewport_meta() {
  // Include the responsive meta to ALL pages except 'form'
  if ( ! is_page( 'form' ) ) {
  ?>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <?php
  endif;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 1.where should I put this Add action Code and to which theme child or parent?  2.where should I remove the viewport meta tag I mean in the child theme or parent theme? I'm not a pro.

Comment: @Sam No worries! 1. The code snippet should go in the `functions.php` file of your child theme. 2. You want to remove the viewport meta tag from the `headers.php` file of your child theme. Basically, child themes allow you to make modifications to any part of your theme without actually modifying your parent theme. That way parent themes can be updated without destroying your modifications. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you so much and I'll try it, and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hey again! I tried what you said and nothing changed! these are the screenshots of the codes: [parent-header](https://prntscr.com/rzfhw0) [child-header](https://prntscr.com/rzfhmi) [child-function](https://prntscr.com/rzfh2n)  . Can we use this : width=device-width, initial-scale=0 instead of 1024 ? 2.did I put the codes in the right places? 3.how about if we do these to the parent codes? why it didn't work ?? Thanks.

Comment: Alright! I just tried and put the codes in the parent files and it perfectly worked!!! Amazing! I put this:width=device-width, initial-scale=0 instead of 1024 and it worked but I had some extra space at the bottom of the page, after the footer. Why?  now If I update the theme it will be removed?  thank you so much I had so much headache for this. You are the best.

Comment: @Sam Edited my answer to include a solution where the view meta is omitted on the page with the 'form' slug.

Comment: @Sam Yes, any changes to the parent theme will be overwritten if it gets updated. You should really use a child theme, if possible.

Comment: I'm trying to do this on my child theme but it seems like my child theme not working! I downloaded the child theme from the official website! As I put codes on the child theme it won't work and no changes, why is it happening?

Comment: @Sam Just to be sure, is your _child theme_ the selected theme? (WordPress → Appearance → Themes)

Comment: Aw!! Stupid Sam!! I didn't select that. and when I select this child all settings will be changed?

Comment: @Sam No worries, we've all been there. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by “settings”, though. Basically, when you select a child theme, WordPress will look for each template (for example, the `header` template) in your child theme's directory first. That way, you can _override_ the templates of your parent theme by copy-pasting its files. So, when you copy-paste the `header.php` file, WordPress will load the one in your child theme. I hope that clears it up :)

Comment: Finally, I did it Bro, Thanks to your clear guide! I activated the child theme and all is well and I'm happy with that. Thank you so much for being my guide. Hope you where around to help me again ;) . Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sam Happy to help! Welcome to Stack Overflow and happy coding :)